# How to create a basic GUI(storing names and addresses in a list) using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r57rO3p1Bcs&feature=youtu.be

So what im trying to do is recreate the gui in the posted video. I have the main window created, and the dialog window. Im brand new to Qt and I have been going over tutorials for all the basics. What I havent been able to find much on is how to go about storing the three values from the "new student" dialog window into the list and how to display the first and last name. I'm also not too sure on how to go about making the values editable.

This is NOT an assignment for any sort of class. I'm trying to learn for my own purposes.
Any sort of strategy for how to link the values from the dialog window to the list, and from the list to main window line edits would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Are you also brand new to C++ or could you code up the data structure to contain this information?

Comment: @Pete Yeah, I've taken a class on objects and ADTs in c++. What did you have in mind?

Comment: If you can create a data structure to hold the info then using the model/view architecture as Zlatomir suggests is the way to go with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is the Qt's [Model/View introduction](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html).

LE: for a simple way to start look at [QListWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qlistwidget.html) class